# Can someone tell how to get the Logged in username of Excel Workbook using C#?

Tags: c#, vsto

I have a VSTO Excel Application in which I need to verify the username of the user from our database then only we will allow to load the data in workbook.

Comment: You need to put in more details to your question. What is it exactly what you need? I think you want to compare the logged in username and check the database to see if he/she is allowed. What you didn't put in is what authentication you'd like to use (Network ID, Windows user ID, other...) and what your database is that you are using. There are many, many databases that are completely different from eachother. So always try to put in as much information you have available. One liners are not likely to get a proper answer. Show what you already tried and what failed/succeeded.

Comment: By the way, other than that you want to use the code in a VSTO application the code you are looking for is a common non VSTO related question. So you might be better served adjusting the tags to other (more) related tags to get a wider scope within the community.

Comment: Check `Environment.UserName` in the `Workbook.Open` Event.

Answer (score 0):

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 

 string getDefaultUserName()
        {
            ExcelApi.Application ap = (ExcelApi.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
            string userName = null;
            try
            {
                userName = ap.UserName;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 

            }
            finally
            {
                if (ap != null)
                {
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ap);
                }
            }
            return userName;
        }
```